# POST / GET compared to submitting form to action page and loading result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I use a website that I'm trying to understand. It has a form where the action states that it sends to a different page.

When you submit this form through the post method, using the website itself it submits and redirects you to the action page. Where it loads information (from the server) based on the form you submitted on the previous page.

However, when I use AJAX post method to submit the form to that page I do not know how to get the page that results from the submission.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: I do not have access to the server.

Edit, further explanation:
Yes. What the page does is submit the form to the page, the page then has additional information from the server that can then be submitted to confirm. I want to write a script that does this from any page.

Comment: what do you mean by i dont get the page that results from the submission. ?

Comment: When you use ajax, the page that results is the current page.  That is the point of ajax - to provide some interaction with the server without a full page load.

Comment: The form submits to another page. I want to load that action page as if I have submitted to it and been redirected.

Literal meaning: I want to post to AND load the action page...

I don't want to redirect. I want access to the result of that submission after it has been run through the action page.

Comment: Does the result page contain a full HTML document? If so, this seems unfeasible, since you would have to parse the resulting document for information you need. You should rewrite the page targeted by your form to return a JSON string, XML (or plain text) instead

Comment: Yes. What the page does is submit the form to the page, the page then has additional information from the server that can then be submitted to confirm.

I want to write a script that does this from any page.

Answer (score 0):

In the page you are POSTing to with AJAX, you could have your code look like this:

```
    if (isset($_POST['var1'], ...) {
        //handle your post variables

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['var1'] = $_POST['var1'];

        echo 'success';
    } else echo 'fail';
```

And then your form page could check the return for either `success` or `fail`.
On success, you would then direct the user's browser to the next page that would read the form elements like:

```
    session_start();
    $var1 = $_SESSION['var1'];

    //use form input
```

Alternatively, instead of returning `success` or `fail`, you could return the url of the page you want to direct the user's browser to.

Comment: I do not have access to the server.